# Are there any recommended internal cable routing systems?

Tags: diy, cable-routing

I'm planning to build a steel frame myself and want it to be fully internally routed (from the head tube). I'll machine a head tube to fit a system. I think the most popular one is the FSA ACR, but I think the head tube is a bit too big (around 55mm), and my down tube is only 38mm. Another problem is that you'll need 2 spaces under the stem, and everyone would like to go sts on a custom bike.
What about specialized or other systems? Which system uses up less space. I would use 12-speed Shimano so only 2 cables are needed.

Comment: I quite like the Speed Concept routing. It’s horrible to work on but SO clean

Comment: To clarify: “sts” = “Slam That Stem” (putting the stem in its lowest possible position)? Probably best to avoid such jargon in a question posed to such a generalist audience

Comment: i think there's a question here (basically what are the options for doing a contemporary fully hidden internal routing on a custom steel bike), but you've left it so open-ended that the answer would have to get very expansive about the pertinent design issues of the bike. what kind of fork and head tube are you using? if you want to create the look and functionality of internally routed around road bikes, which is almost all strictly cosmetic in intention, are you willing to accept the weight penalty of using a chunky steel head tube? do you have the tooling to miter non-round tubes?

Comment: Bordering on a shopping/product recommendation.   Please provide answers that avoid recommendations and focus on technicalities.

Comment: @Noise - It's kinda impossible to adopt that kind of system to a steel frame, given that's a TT bike. And also for these systems that only a single brand uses, it's hard to find the dimensions and make a custom headset. There's a Specialized shop near my home so I think I could take a look at a stem they have. But I would stick to ACR if SP doesn't allow a  slimmer head tube.

Comment: @NathanKnutson - As I've mentioned, I'll use a custom CNCed head tube. The fork will be a Yoeleo R11 fork which supports routing the hydro hose from the steerer tube (don't worry about its quality). And I will do all the mitering by hand because I don't have a mil. I've decided to build a steel bike so weight is out of concern. Also, it is possible to internal cable route with a round head tube if it's large enough.

Comment: And have you also looked at the Deda integrated system, that is quite easy to get parts for and looks relatively straightforward to integrate

Comment: https://dedaelementi.com/dcr-tech

Comment: Can’t you have the cables enter just behind the head tube and live with visible cables from the handlebar to the head tube? Running cables through cut-outs in the headset bearings/bearing covers looks like it has a ton of downsides.

Comment: @Michael No, because I would like this bike to be as aesthetically pleasing as possible. And I basically don't care about hard maintenance or whatever.

Comment: @Noise That's a great one, but the two systems are basically the same (0.1mm larger). I'd rather go with FSA as it's more accessible in my area.

Answer (score 1):

In the interests of simplicity, I would suggest that you design your frame with access ports in some of these locations:

- Top of downtube
- Rear of chainstay - both sides, for rear derailleur and rear disk caliper
- Bottom bracket area, maybe several
- Seat tube, one for a front derailleur and potentially for a dropper post
- Top tube, allow for a rear rim brake cable.

Allow for extra reinforcement here so the frame tubes don't have a weakness despite the holes.

Then design and 3D print some plugs that suit your **current** needs.  Maybe you blank off the rear disk caliper brake access because you have a rim brake  currently.

I would simply run full-length housing from shifter downward, passing it through the covers and inside the frame.   Some frames have permanently-secured internal guidance and some leave the internal wires flopping in the breeze.

Consider the future too - try and allow for future stuff like DI2 wiring and batteries, disk brake caliper mounts, some lugs for mudguards/racks and top-tube lugs for frame bag and food bag.   You can always print new plugs if you choose to add another cable through a hole (like adding an airhorn/permanent light wires, or changing from cable-disks to hydraulic disks.)

Not everything is possible but going to this effort+expense requires careful thought. Good luck!

Comment: In terms of aesthetics, there's little difference between half internal routing and non internal cable routing. I would like fully integrated ones using weird shaped headset spacers. But the thing is that it's hard to DIY a stem and almost impossible to make custom bearings. so I'll need to stick with a present system.